# How to Inflate a view / layout into another sub layout?

Tags: android

I have required to add inflate layout in sub layout of android.

For example

I am using Layout a,b,c,d.

I have required to set inflated layout in c layout.

It is possible to set the layout of sub layout?

Thanks!!
Regards,
Ani

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then, yes, you can do it.  Just inflate your sublayout using LayoutInflator - you'll get a View.  Then simply add that View to your parent layout.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! I'm going on memory here so the actual code could be different.
Layouts should have an `addView(View v)` method. If you want to add `View b` to `View a`, you should be able to do `a.addView(b);`